# Cursor and table cannot be found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a procedure that will select MAX from some tables, but for some reason it is not able to find these tables. Could anybody help me?

```
declare
varible1 varchar2 (255);
temp varchar2 (255);
last_val number(9,0);
 cursor c1 is Select distinct table_name from user_tab_cols order by table_name;
begin
FOR asd in c1
LOOP
temp := asd.table_name;
varible1  := '"'||temp||'"';
select max("id") into last_val from varible1 ;
END LOOP;
end;
```

For example, the first table name is acceptance_form and for select I need to use "acceptance_form".

Code after edit:

```
declare
varible1 varchar2 (255);
temp varchar2 (255);
last_val number(9,0);
 cursor c1 is Select distinct table_name from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'id';
begin
FOR asd in c1
LOOP
temp := asd.table_name;
execute immediate 'select NVL(max('||'id'||'),0) from "'||varible1||'"' into last_val;
END LOOP;
end;
```

Can't cuz db is Case sensitive Oracle express 10g tables and rows was created like this

```
CREATE TABLE "ADMINMME"."acceptance_form"
(
    "group_id" NUMBER(9, 0), 
    "id" NUMBER(4, 0) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL , 
    "is_deleted" NUMBER(4, 0), 
    "name" NVARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL 
);
```

Can u tell me how to handle exception sequence dosn't exist for this;
Nevermind exception was in wrong block :)

```
declare
temp varchar2 (255);
last_val number(9,0);
 cursor c1 is Select distinct table_name from user_tab_cols where column_name = 'id';
begin
FOR asd in c1
LOOP
temp := asd.table_name;
execute immediate 'select NVL(max("id"),0)+1 from "'||temp||'"' into last_val;
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop sequence "seq_'|| temp||'"';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create SEQUENCE "seq_'|| temp ||'" MINVALUE '||last_val||'MAXVALUE                 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||temp||'.nextval from dual';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE "seq_'||temp||'" INCREMENT BY 1';
exception when others then
null;
end;
END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Your cursor is now better, but use uppercase for column_name: `column_name = 'ID'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic sql doesn't work in that way.

```
declare
varible1 varchar2 (255);
temp varchar2 (255);
last_val number(9,0);
 cursor c1 is Select distinct table_name from user_tab_cols order by table_name;
begin
  FOR asd in c1
  LOOP
  temp := asd.table_name;
  begin
    execute immediate 'select max(id) from '||temp into last_val;
    dbms_output.put_line('max(id) for table: ' ||temp||' = '||last_val);
  exception when others then
     dbms_output.put_line('Failed to get max(id) for table: ' ||temp);
  end;
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: How i can handle exception if max ID dosnt exist?

Comment: you can catch it adding a begin end block. But you can test if column id exists... I'll edit my answer to add exception catching.

Comment: I got that  done now but idk why it telling me Error report:
ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier
ORA-06512: at line 10
01741. 00000 -  "illegal zero-length identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: you can use `Select table_name from user_tables order by table_name`

Comment: Corrected. Should select `max(id)` not `max('||id||')`

Comment: check the new code i gave and it says that error zero-lenght idk why ;/

Comment: ah, select from temp, not from variable1. I have eliminated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable for the table name.

What you can do is creating the complete sql statement as a string and use execute immediate

Here are some examples how to do that: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD